# Meteor JS (Iron Router) - Restricting access to server routes

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a download route in my MeteorJs app which i want to restrict access to. The route code is as follows

```
Router.route("/download-data",  function() {
var data = Meteor.users.find({ "profile.user_type": "employee" }).fetch();
var fields = [...fields];

var title = "Employee - Users";

var file = Excel.export(title, fields, data);

var headers = {
  "Content-type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats",
  "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + title + ".xlsx"
};

 this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
 this.response.end(file, "binary");
 },
 { where: "server" }
);
```

The route automatically downloads a file. This is currently working but I want to restrict access to the route. I only want admins to be able to download it.

I have created an `onBeforeAction` Hook as below

```
Router.onBeforeAction(
  function() {
    //using alanning:roles
    if(Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, "admin"){
     console.log('message') //testing
   }
  },
  {
    only: ["downloadData"]
  }
);
```

and renamed my route as below

```
//code above
this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
 this.response.end(file, "binary");
 },
 { where: "server", name: "downloadData" }
);
```

The `onBeforeAcion` hook does not take any effect

Also I noticed neither `this.userId` nor `Meteor.userId` works on the route

Answer (score 1):

For the server side hook, I am pretty sure you need the onBeforeAction to have the { where: "server" } part as you do for your route.

Also, I don't think iron:router ever implemented server side user auth on their routing. You may want to check into a package around server routing with larger features such as mhagmajer:server-router that has access to authenticated routes.

https://github.com/mhagmajer/server-router